# How to grab X POS every time image is added document.createElement("img");

Tags: javascript, css, html

[EXAMPLE PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zss7l.png)
I have a problem getting X every time. When it grabs doc2.left a couple of times, it then stops and stays at 0. So the problem is, gX1 will stay at 0 after the first couple of times it graps doc2.left.

It reaches the edged of the page(even when the web page is not maximized) it stops reading doc2.left.

Any Ideas?

```
var cTAdd = 0;
var setThis = 1;
var GAPlayer = 3;

var gX1 = 0;
var gX2 = 0;
var gX3 = 0;
var gX4 = 0;
var gX5 = 0;
var gX6 = 0;

var getX1 = 0;
var getX2 = 0;
var getX3 = 0;
var getX4 = 0;
var getX5 = 0;
var getX6 = 0;


var getH = 0;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// MOVE PLATFORMS

var cFunc = 0;
function landT() {
    setThis = setTimeout(landT, 400);


        cTAdd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //
        // BOTTOM ROW

        var block00 = document.createElement("img");
        var block02 = document.createElement("img"); // ADD SEPERATION BLOCK(BLOCK HOLE)

        if (cTAdd > 0 && cTAdd < 40) {
            block00.src = "images/sep2.png";
        }

        if (cTAdd > 40 && cTAdd < 80) {
            block02.src = "images/sep1.png"; // ADD SEPERATION BLOCK(BLOCK HOLE)
        }

        if (cTAdd > 80 && cTAdd < 100) {
            block00.src = "images/platform00.png";
        }

        document.getElementById("land01").appendChild(block00);
        document.getElementById("land01").appendChild(block02); // APPEND CHILD(BLOCK HOLE)
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //
        // BLOCK02 GET X POS OF ADDED BLOCK 

        if (getX1 == 0) { //////////////////////////////////////////// SET (BLOCK HOLE) X
            var doc2 = block02.getBoundingClientRect();
            gX1 = doc2.left;
            getX1 = 1;
        }


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //
        // TOP ROW

        var block01 = document.createElement("img");

        if (cTAdd > 0 && cTAdd < 25) {
            block01.src = "images/platform00.png";
        }
        if (cTAdd > 25 && cTAdd < 50) {
            block01.src = "images/sep2.png";
        }
        if (cTAdd > 50 && cTAdd < 100) {
            block01.src = "images/sep1.png";
        }

        document.getElementById("land00").appendChild(block01);


        GAPlayer = GAPlayer + 3; // SET PLAYER DOCUMENT.IMAGES[]




}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// MOVE PLATFORMS 

var thisSet = 1;
var cPlayer = 0;
var moveSpeed = 5;
var xPos = 50;
var yPos = 300;
function moveLand() {

    thisSet = setTimeout(moveLand, 30);

    if (xPos >= 350 && moveL == 1) {
        moveBlock1 = moveBlock1 - 15;
        document.getElementById("land00").style.left = moveBlock1 + "px";
        document.getElementById("land01").style.left = moveBlock1 + "px";
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // X POSITION OF (BLOCK HOLE)

    if (gX1 > 0 && movePR == 1 && xPos >= 350) {
        gX1 = gX1 - 15;
    }
    if (getX1 == 1 && gX1 == 0) {
        getX1 = 0;
    }
    if (gX1 < 0) {
        gX1 = 0;    
    }


    console.log("X1: " + gX1); // CONSOLE/LOG gX1 

}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// MOVE PLAYER

var setP = 1;
var yMax = 18;
function moveP() {
    setP = setTimeout(moveP, 10);


    if (movePR == 1) {
        movePL = 0;
        xPos = xPos + moveSpeed;

        cPlayer++;
        if (cPlayer >= 4) 
            cPlayer = 0;
            document.images[GAPlayer].src = gPlayer[cPlayer].src;
    }


    if (movePL == 1) {
        movePR = 0;
        xPos = xPos - moveSpeed;

        cPlayer++;
        if (cPlayer >= 4) 
            cPlayer = 0;
            document.images[GAPlayer].src = gPlayer[cPlayer].src;
    }


    if (movePU == 1) {
        yMax--;
        yPos = yPos -= yMax
    }
    if (yMax <= 0) {
        movePU = 2;
    }
    if (movePU == 2) {
        yMax++;
        yPos = yPos += yMax;    
    }
    if (yMax >= 18) {
        movePU = 0;
    }
    if (yPos >= 300) {
        yPos = 300;
    }


    document.getElementById("player").style.left = xPos + "px";
    document.getElementById("player").style.top = yPos + "px";  


    if (xPos >= 350) {
        xPos = 350; 
    }
    if (xPos <= 50) {
        xPos = 50;  
    }   
}
```

Comment: I also realized it has to do something with the setTimeout

Comment: I actually switched to canvas.